# Getting a Syntax error while defining a function

Tags: python, function, python-3.x

Getting a syntax error on the apostrophe in this line

```
def filecopy('example.txt','output.txt'):  #<- Error here on the "'"
    infile = open('example.txt',)
    text = infile.read()
    infile.close()
    infile = open('output.txt')
    outfile.write(text)
    infile.close()
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be variable names?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have literals like that in a function declaration, it looks like your are confusing the declaration from the calling of a function:

```
def filecopy(infile, outfile):
    ...

# Later call the function
filecopy('example.txt','output.txt')
```

You can have default arguments:

```
def filecopy(infile='example.txt', outfile='output.txt'):
    ...

# But you still need to call it
filecopy()
# or
filecopy('fred.txt', 'wilma.txt')
```

Comment: @Jerry Scirica Please accept the answer if it helps you.